# Gnuplot: Setting the range of a third (colored) point

Tags: gnuplot

When plotting color-maps using gnuplot, I usually use the following lines:

```
  ...
  set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
  plot "file.dat" using 1:2:3 with points pointtype '7' palette
```

Usually the range of the third point (appearing in the legend) is automatically set by gnuplot. But how can I change that? say I want the range of the 3rd point to be from 0 to 1500.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is actually a really good question -- assuming you mean that you want the colorbar range to be determined (not the legend [i.e. key] -- the legend doesn't typically have that information).

My first thought was `set cbrange`.  This might do what you want --

```
set cbrange [0:1500]
set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
plot "file.dat" u 1:2:3 w p pt 7 palette
```

However, the question is then "What do you want to happen to out of range points?"  This solution will move out of range points to the bottom/top of the scale (e.g. purple for negative numbers, red for numbers greater than 1500).  My next thought was that you should be able to clip those points out by `set zrange [0:1500]` -- But that doesn't work.  You have at least 2 options at this point.

**Option 1:** use splot:

```
set view map
set cbrange [0:1500]
set zrange [0:1500]
set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
splot "file.dat" u 1:2:3 w p pt 7 palette
```

Your borders will be slightly different than they were before, but that's no real big deal.

**Option 2:** filter with the ternary operator (which you already know about from your previous question):

```
set cbrange [0:1500]
set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
inrange(c)=((c>=0) && (c<=1500))? c : (1/0)
plot "file.dat" u 1:2:(inrange($3)) w p pt 7 palette
```

Also, for plotting color maps, you may want to look into the `pm3d` plotting style (`image` might work too).  You might need to restructure your datafile slightly, but plotting color maps is that plotting style's bread-and-butter.